# Select the first row with specific column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, multithreading, locking

i have a table being accessed by multiple threads. The table contains a column with the row status i.e "Dialed" if it had already been processed and "Not Dialled" if it isn't . I would want to

```
Select first row where status = "not Dialled" (Read Past ).
```

I am using readpast so that multiple threads can have different rows and no deadlock happens.

Is the use of Read Past ok here and secondly how can I get the first row always

Comment: What means _"how to get the first row always"_? The first row where `status="not dialled`? That's simply `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table WHERE STATUS='not Dialled'`. But i think you have another column to `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I believe i can add a column to order by . Thanks i am testing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use "Top" clause like this.

```
Select Top 1
    *
    From Data
        Where status = "not Dialled"
        ;
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The TOP clause is used to specify the number of records to return.
Note: Not all database systems support the TOP clause.

**SQL Server Syntax:**
SELECT TOP number|percent column_name(s) 
FROM table_name

**MySQL Syntax:**
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
LIMIT number
Example

**Oracle Syntax:**
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE ROWNUM <= number

Further Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp